# copyToOutput is not set in .nuspec even though it is set in the csproj file for the content

Tags: .net-core, nuget, visual-studio-2019, csproj

I have this set in .csproj file

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="powershellcert.pfx" >
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

But when I see the .nuspec file from the generated nuget package generated for the project it does not have **copyToOutput** set for the above content

```
<contentFiles>
  <files include="any/netcoreapp3.1/Properties/launchSettings.json" buildAction="Content" />
  <files include="any/netcoreapp3.1/powershellcert.pfx" buildAction="Content" />
</contentFiles
```

Not sure if I am missing sth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<PackageCopyToOutput>`

so:

```xml
<Content Include="powershellcert.pfx" >
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    <Pack>true</Pack>
    <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
</Content>
```

PS not sure if `<Pack>` is needed.

See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#including-content-in-a-package)